# Сортировка с использованием рекурсии

Tags: рекурсия, сортировка, java

Всем привет.

Начал разбираться с быстрой сортировкой, и возникла масса вопросов. В книге смутно описано, на обучалках в ютубе совсем крах. В общем, вот ниже код с комментариями в виде вопросов:

```
private static void qs(int items[],int left, int right){

    int i,j;
    int x,y;

    i = left; j = right;

     x = items[(left+right)/2];

    do {
        while ((items[i]<x) && (i<right)) i++;
        while ((x<items[j]) && (j > left)) j--;

        // Мы сравниваем индексы массива или их значения??
        if (i <= j) {

            y = items[i];
            items[i] = items[j];
            items[j] = y;
            i++;j--;

        }
    } while (i<=j);
        // Для чего оператор if не совсем понятно?
    if (left<j) qs(items,left,j);
      if(i<right) qs(items,i,right);

}

}
```

Comment: 1. Сравниваются индексы, вы сортируете до тех пор, пока они не пересекутся.
2. Оператор if опять же для этих целей нужен, хотя бы по той причине, что если бы его не было, было бы бесконечная рекурсия.

Советую в таких непониманиях сперва проделывать алгоритм на бумажке с небольшим массивом на 6-10 элементов, например.

Comment: Я проделывал прежложенный вами вариант. Но возникают ньюансы: почему мы сравниваем индексы, если они в любом раскладе будут левый меньше правого, т.к. нумерация их идет от 0 до макс. длины массива. Индекс левой части от операнда будет меньше индекса правой части, а значения под этими индексами совершенно другие.

Comment: Тут следует понять суть быстрой сортировки, не глядя в код. Я так понимаю, что у вас такого понимания ещё нет. Суть в том что просматриваются две половины массива и ищутся элементы, находящиеся в неверном порядке. При нахождении такого они меняются местами. И так пока i и j не пересекутся. Затем происходит аналогичные рекурсивные вызовы, только для половин исходных, то есть они делятся ещё раз пополам.
1 шаг - массив пополам  
2 шаг - половины предыдущего шага пополам  
и т.д.